# VS Code Formatting JSX with new lines

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier

I've recently started coding with React, and I noticed immediately that VS Code is formatting my react files as follows, which is causing all kinds of warnings from the linter.

> Index.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      div className = "App" >
      <
      header className = "App-header" >
      <
      img src = {
        logo
      }
      className = "App-logo"
      alt = "logo" / >
      <
      p >
      Edit < code > src / App.js < /code> and save to reload. < /
      p > <
      a className = "App-link"
      href = "https://reactjs.org"
      target = "_blank"
      rel = "noopener noreferrer" >
      Learn React <
      /a> < /
      header > <
      /div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm having trouble finding the Prettier setting or whatever other setting is causing this in the app, any suggestions?

Extensions (Note WSL Ubuntu Windows)

- Bracket Pair Colorizer
- Debugger for Chrome
- Javascript (ES6) Code Snippets
- React Nitro Snippets
- Reactjs code snippets
- Remote - WSL
- Vue Theme
- Autoprefixer
- Beautify
- City Lights Icon Package
- EditorConfig for VS Code
- ESLint
- Github Pull Requests and Issues
- GitLens - Git Supercharged
- Import Cost
- Live Server
- npm
- npm IntelliSense
- Path IntelliSense
- Prettier - Code Formatter
- React Extension Pack
- React Nitro Essentials
- Search node_modules
- SonarLint
- Vetur
- vue-beautify

### **VS Code About Block:**

- Version: 1.48.0-insider (user setup)
- Commit: 459610f3ef11b956968afadff704bad3bc1a0de2
- Date: 2020-08-04T12:40:10.231Z
- Electron: 7.3.2
- Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
- Node.js: 12.8.1 V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
- OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363

Comment: Check your local Beautify config.

Answer (score 5):

You need to choose the default formatter.

1. Press `Ctrl+Shift+P`(Win) or `Cmd+Shift+P`(Mac)
2. Type *Format Document With...*
3. Then click *Configure Default Formatter...* and choose it from the list.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should download Prettier. Then go to **Settings** and check(the checkbox) '***Prettier: JSX Bracket Same Line***' It should work well

Comment: If you look at the post, you'll see I had Prettier installed. I tried this, it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: It's not working at all mate.

Answer (score 1):

Just Install Preitter Extensions On VS CODE it will reformat all your file

[image]

Comment: Look at my post--I had Prettier installed. This wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably is due to conflicting format tools available in vs code. To solve this

1. Press `Ctrl+Shift+P`(windows) or `Cmd+Shift+P`(Mac)
2. Type `Format Document With...`
3. Select `Configure default Formatter...`
4. Choose an option for format going forward. (If you are choosing vs code's inbuilt format tool, better disable/remove other code format extensions)
5. Select All `Ctrl+A`(Windows) or `Cmd+A`(Mac) and press `Ctrl+K Ctrl+F`(windows) or `Cmd+K Cmd+F` to format the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the prettier extension in Visual Studio Code, try adding this to the settings.json file:

```
"editor.insertSpaces": false,
"editor.tabSize": 4,
"editor.detectIndentation": false,

"prettier.tabWidth": 4,
"prettier.useTabs": true  // This made it finally work for me
```

Well, if you like the developer way, Visual Studio Code allows you to specify the different file types for the tabSize. Here is the example of my settings.json with default four spaces and JavaScript/JSON two spaces:

```
{
 // I want my default to be 4, but JavaScript/JSON to be 2
 "editor.tabSize": 4,
 "[javascript]": {
  "editor.tabSize": 2
 },
"[json]": {
 "editor.tabSize": 2
 },

 // This one forces the tab to be **space**
"editor.insertSpaces": true
}
```